# Delete properties and then sum other values in array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I want to be able to sum of value inside my array of objects based on the value of another key-value pair in object.

Based on the value of `cat` I want to sum the values of `val1, val2, val3`.

I have an array of objects:

```
let json = [
      {cat: 'abc', device: 'iphone',   site: 'google', val1:10, val2:20, val3:30},
      {cat: 'abc', device: 'iphone',  site: 'bing', val1:23, val2:12, val3:14},
      {cat: 'abc', device: 'iphone',  site: 'jeeves', val1:67, val2:78, val3:12},
      {cat: 'pqr',  device: 'ipad',  site: 'google', val1:10, val2:20, val3:30},
      {cat: 'pqr',  device: 'ipad',  site: 'bing', val1:23, val2:12, val3:14},
      {cat: 'pqr',  device: 'ipad',  site: 'jeeves', val1:67, val2:78, val3:12},
      {cat: 'xyz',  device: 'mac',   site: 'google', val1:10, val2:20, val3:30},
      {cat: 'xyz',  device: 'mac',   site: 'bing', val1:23, val2:12, val3:14},
      {cat: 'xyz',  device: 'mac',   site: 'jeeves', val1:67, val2:78, val3:12}
]
```

To start I decided to remove the other 2 fields,

I have an array with the keys I want to remove: `let arr= ['device', 'site'];`

```js
let json = [
      {cat: 'abc', device: 'iphone',   site: 'google', val1:10, val2:20, val3:30},
      {cat: 'abc', device: 'iphone',  site: 'bing', val1:23, val2:12, val3:14},
      {cat: 'abc', device: 'iphone',  site: 'jeeves', val1:67, val2:78, val3:12},
      {cat: 'pqr',  device: 'ipad',  site: 'google', val1:10, val2:20, val3:30},
      {cat: 'pqr',  device: 'ipad',  site: 'bing', val1:23, val2:12, val3:14},
      {cat: 'pqr',  device: 'ipad',  site: 'jeeves', val1:67, val2:78, val3:12},
      {cat: 'xyz',  device: 'mac',   site: 'google', val1:10, val2:20, val3:30},
      {cat: 'xyz',  device: 'mac',   site: 'bing', val1:23, val2:12, val3:14},
      {cat: 'xyz',  device: 'mac',   site: 'jeeves', val1:67, val2:78, val3:12}
]

let arr= ['device', 'site'];

json.forEach(d=>{
    arr.forEach(a=>{
    delete d[a];
  });
});

console.log(json);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Is there a neater more scalable way to do this rather than 2 `forEaches`? I also want to be able to sum the values of `val1, val2, val3`.

This is my expected value:

```
[
   {cat:'abc', val1:100, val2:110, val3:56},
   {cat:'pqr', val1:100, val2:110, val3:56},
   {cat:'xyz', val1:100, val2:110, val3:56}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fun (I've already answered above, but I don't want to pollute a potentially useful answer with needlessly abstruse code)... we could parameterise (curry) the reducing function, to make it reusable in other contexts, something like this:

```js
let json = [
  {cat: 'abc', device: 'iphone',   site: 'google', val1:10, val2:20, val3:30},
  {cat: 'abc', device: 'iphone',  site: 'bing', val1:23, val2:12, val3:14},
  {cat: 'abc', device: 'iphone',  site: 'jeeves', val1:67, val2:78, val3:12},
  {cat: 'pqr',  device: 'ipad',  site: 'google', val1:10, val2:20, val3:30},
  {cat: 'pqr',  device: 'ipad',  site: 'bing', val1:23, val2:12, val3:14},
  {cat: 'pqr',  device: 'ipad',  site: 'jeeves', val1:67, val2:78, val3:12},
  {cat: 'xyz',  device: 'mac',   site: 'google', val1:10, val2:20, val3:30},
  {cat: 'xyz',  device: 'mac',   site: 'bing', val1:23, val2:12, val3:14},
  {cat: 'xyz',  device: 'mac',   site: 'jeeves', val1:67, val2:78, val3:15}  //modifed to check
]

const sumByGroup = ({
    groupByField,
    valueFields,
    sumFunction = (acc,cur) => (acc || 0) + cur,
}) => (
    acc,{[groupByField]:group,...values}
) => {
  acc[group] = acc[group] || { [groupByField]: group };
  valueFields.forEach(
    (f) => acc[group][f] = sumFunction(acc[group][f], values[f])
  );
  return acc;
}

const res = Object.values(
  json
    //.map(({device,site,...rest}) => ({...rest}))    // remove device & site
    .reduce(sumByGroup({
      groupByField: "cat", 
      valueFields:["val1", "val2", "val3"]
    }), {})
);

console.log(res);
```

If you follow this line of thinking, it's probably worth using a library eventually. [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/) has a function [reduceBy](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#reduceBy) which does this job. See [live example here](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.27.0#?const%20json%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%7Bcat%3A%20%27abc%27%2C%20device%3A%20%27iphone%27%2C%20%20%20site%3A%20%27google%27%2C%20val1%3A10%2C%20val2%3A20%2C%20val3%3A30%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7Bcat%3A%20%27abc%27%2C%20device%3A%20%27iphone%27%2C%20%20site%3A%20%27bing%27%2C%20val1%3A23%2C%20val2%3A12%2C%20val3%3A14%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7Bcat%3A%20%27abc%27%2C%20device%3A%20%27iphone%27%2C%20%20site%3A%20%27jeeves%27%2C%20val1%3A67%2C%20val2%3A78%2C%20val3%3A12%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7Bcat%3A%20%27pqr%27%2C%20%20device%3A%20%27ipad%27%2C%20%20site%3A%20%27google%27%2C%20val1%3A10%2C%20val2%3A20%2C%20val3%3A30%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7Bcat%3A%20%27pqr%27%2C%20%20device%3A%20%27ipad%27%2C%20%20site%3A%20%27bing%27%2C%20val1%3A23%2C%20val2%3A12%2C%20val3%3A14%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7Bcat%3A%20%27pqr%27%2C%20%20device%3A%20%27ipad%27%2C%20%20site%3A%20%27jeeves%27%2C%20val1%3A67%2C%20val2%3A78%2C%20val3%3A12%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7Bcat%3A%20%27xyz%27%2C%20%20device%3A%20%27mac%27%2C%20%20%20site%3A%20%27google%27%2C%20val1%3A10%2C%20val2%3A20%2C%20val3%3A30%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7Bcat%3A%20%27xyz%27%2C%20%20device%3A%20%27mac%27%2C%20%20%20site%3A%20%27bing%27%2C%20val1%3A23%2C%20val2%3A12%2C%20val3%3A14%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7Bcat%3A%20%27xyz%27%2C%20%20device%3A%20%27mac%27%2C%20%20%20site%3A%20%27jeeves%27%2C%20val1%3A67%2C%20val2%3A78%2C%20val3%3A15%7D%20%20%2F%2Fmodifed%20to%20check%0A%5D%0A%0Aconst%20reducer%20%3D%20%28acc%2Ccur%29%3D%3E%0A%20%20R.mapObjIndexed%28%28val%2C%20key%2C%20obj%29%20%3D%3E%20val%20%2B%20cur%5Bkey%5D%20%2Cacc%29%0A%3B%0Aconst%20fieldsWithDefaults%20%3D%20%7B%27val1%27%3A0%2C%27val2%27%3A0%2C%27val3%27%3A0%7D%3B%0Aconst%20groupFn%20%3D%20R.prop%28%27cat%27%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20res%20%3D%20R.reduceBy%28reducer%2C%20fieldsWithDefaults%2C%20groupFn%2C%20json%29%20%3B%0A%0Ares%0A%2F%2FJSON.stringify%28res%2Cnull%2C2%29%0A).

```js
const json = [
  {cat: 'abc', device: 'iphone',   site: 'google', val1:10, val2:20, val3:30},
  {cat: 'abc', device: 'iphone',  site: 'bing', val1:23, val2:12, val3:14},
  // [...]
  {cat: 'xyz',  device: 'mac',   site: 'jeeves', val1:67, val2:78, val3:15}  //modifed to check
]
const reducer = (acc,cur)=>
  R.mapObjIndexed((val, key, obj) => val + cur[key] ,acc)
;
const fieldsWithDefaults = {'val1':0,'val2':0,'val3':0};
const groupFn = R.prop('cat');
const res = R.reduceBy(reducer, fieldsWithDefaults, groupFn, json) ;
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a textbook use case for the array.prototype.reduce function. It is intended to iterate over an array and combine values together.

```js
const thing = json.reduce((accumulator, item) => {
  // Get the important values from the item.
  const { cat, val1, val2, val3 } = item;

  // If this aggregation hasn't been initialized yet, initialize it.
  if (!(cat in accumulator)) {
    accumulator[cat] = {
      cat,
      val1: 0,
      val2: 0,
      val3: 0,
    };
  }

  // Add the values from the current item to the accumulator.
  accumulator[cat].val1 += val1;
  accumulator[cat].val2 += val2;
  accumulator[cat].val3 += val3;

  // Record progress.
  return accumulator;
}, {})

// Object.values converts an object back into an array.
console.log(Object.values(thing));
```

Comment: Thank you for responding! Just what I need. Is there a way for me to make this dynamic without mentioning va1, val2, val3?

Comment: Is there a way to make this dynamic?

Comment: Essentially the same idea as mine - but elegant!

Comment: You could do some kind of loop over Object.keys(item) to define the fields you want to aggregate. However, it may make more sense just to turn val1, val2, and val3 into an array.

Comment: @phhu Yeah, I was sandboxing when you posted. It's the way to go.

Comment: @CharlesBamford, Sorry I am new to this. How do I do that? Thank you again

Answer (score 2):

This kind of problem can often be handled by chaining map, reduce and filter functions, as in this slightly inelegant but working example:

```js
let json = [
      {cat: 'abc', device: 'iphone',   site: 'google', val1:10, val2:20, val3:30},
      {cat: 'abc', device: 'iphone',  site: 'bing', val1:23, val2:12, val3:14},
      {cat: 'abc', device: 'iphone',  site: 'jeeves', val1:67, val2:78, val3:12},
      {cat: 'pqr',  device: 'ipad',  site: 'google', val1:10, val2:20, val3:30},
      {cat: 'pqr',  device: 'ipad',  site: 'bing', val1:23, val2:12, val3:14},
      {cat: 'pqr',  device: 'ipad',  site: 'jeeves', val1:67, val2:78, val3:12},
      {cat: 'xyz',  device: 'mac',   site: 'google', val1:10, val2:20, val3:30},
      {cat: 'xyz',  device: 'mac',   site: 'bing', val1:23, val2:12, val3:14},
      {cat: 'xyz',  device: 'mac',   site: 'jeeves', val1:67, val2:78, val3:12}
]

const valueFields = ["val1", "val2", "val3"];

const res = Object.values(
  json
  //.map(({device,site,...rest}) => ({...rest}))    // remove device & site 
  .reduce((acc,{cat,...values})=> {
    acc[cat] = acc[cat] || {cat};
    valueFields.forEach(
      (field) => (acc[cat][field] = (acc[cat][field] || 0) + values[field])
    );
    return acc;
  }, {})
);

console.log(res);
```

The `map` handles the removal of device and site by mapping the rest of the properties to a new array. But it isn't necessary, because we get rid of these in the next step, so it's commented out.

The `reduce` does the work: for each row, take its category and make a default value for it if it hasn't been seen before. Then add the rows vals to those extracted on previous iterations of the loop.

Object.values is used to get an array from the object returned by reduce.

This functional code isn't the most elegent (ideas for improvement?), but it has the benefit of allowing the operation to be broken down into steps, without mutating the original data.

Comment: I don't know if removing device and site is necessary. I believe the question asker was trying to simplify the problem of the reduce function.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Can I use `arr` instead of `device` and `site`? I could have a lot more fields.

Comment: I've updated the code a little, putting the value fields in an array, and simplifying the code a little

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: Charles Bamford's answer below is a study for me of eloquence in JS code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array#reduce` with a dynamic array of keys to sum.

```js
let json = [
      {cat: 'abc', device: 'iphone',   site: 'google', val1:10, val2:20, val3:30},
      {cat: 'abc', device: 'iphone',  site: 'bing', val1:23, val2:12, val3:14},
      {cat: 'abc', device: 'iphone',  site: 'jeeves', val1:67, val2:78, val3:12},
      {cat: 'pqr',  device: 'ipad',  site: 'google', val1:10, val2:20, val3:30},
      {cat: 'pqr',  device: 'ipad',  site: 'bing', val1:23, val2:12, val3:14},
      {cat: 'pqr',  device: 'ipad',  site: 'jeeves', val1:67, val2:78, val3:12},
      {cat: 'xyz',  device: 'mac',   site: 'google', val1:10, val2:20, val3:30},
      {cat: 'xyz',  device: 'mac',   site: 'bing', val1:23, val2:12, val3:14},
      {cat: 'xyz',  device: 'mac',   site: 'jeeves', val1:67, val2:78, val3:12}
]

let arr= ['device', 'site'];
let sumKeys = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3'];
let sumBy = 'cat';
let res = json.reduce((acc,curr)=>{
  let prev = acc[curr[sumBy]];
  if(prev){
    sumKeys.forEach(key=>prev[key] += curr[key]);
  } else {
    acc[curr[sumBy]] = curr;
    arr.forEach(key=>delete curr[key]);
  }
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(res);
```